# Trouble with Boost test with argc and argv

Tags: c++11, boost-test

I am getting very frustrated in trying to getting Boost test to
use argc and argv.  Based on other answers from Stack Overflow, the
following code (with Boost 1.67.0) is the closest I've gotten.  However,
it won't compile, because it expects an extra }.  I have put an extra }
in various places, and have tried many other things, but I can't for the
life of me get this to work.  EDIT: the code has balanced {}.  I suspect some subtlety having to do with the Boost macros, but I can't tell what it is.

Will someone please tell me specifically what changes to make this code
compile and do what it is supposed to do.  Right now, I am very highly 
frustrated.

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE how_to
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

struct F_ArgsFixture {
   F_ArgsFixture()
   : argc(boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite().argc),
     argv(boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite().argv)
   {
   }

   ~F_ArgsFixture() {}

   int argc;
   char **argv;
};

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE( how_to, F_ArgsFixture )

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE( test_name1, F_ArgsFixture )
{
   F_ArgsFixture FF;
   string x = FF.argv[1];
   cout << "1 " << x << endl;
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE( test_name2, F_ArgsFixture )
{
   F_ArgsFixture FF;
   string x = FF.argv[1];
   cout << "2 " << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: FYI, I expanded the documentation about command line handling, should be in boost 1.70.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures/case.html) indicates, the problems with your code are the following:

- `BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE` declares the fixture for each of the test-case of the suite, so there is no need to call `BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE` inside the test-suite, and `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` is enough
- `BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE` starts a new test-suite, and this test suite should be closed by `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()`

A version of the code that compiles can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/GihOSx)